# After replacing 4 tires on a Hyundai Elantra 2012

Tags: tires, noise, hyundai, elantra

When I turn the steering wheel all the way right or left there is a thumping sound and feel. What can it be?

Comment: First thing comes mind is CV axle.

Comment: Correct sizes fitted or do they rub now?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you get an alignment done? While not absolutely necessary, it's ALWAYS a good thing to do when getting new tires to ensure they don't get worn prematurely. A bad alignment can cause excess noise from new tires as well.

Comment: Is this only when the vehicle is moving, or does it also do it when stationary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The sound or thumping occurs when driving or standing still if I turn the wheel all the way right or left. The tires are they correct size and wheels were aligned